# Retrieving validator error messages in Laravel 4

Tags: php, json, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm writing an AJAX method which returns a JSON response and I'm validating some POST data that's sent to this method. I'm wondering if it's possible for me to extract the current error message from the validator if validation fails, like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => array(), // I want the error message to be available here
        200
    ));
}
```

So far all I've found is a way to pass the error messages to a view using `withErrors($validator);`. But because I'm not using a view and just returning a response with `Response::json()`, I can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => array( $validator->messages()->all() ), // I want the error message to be available here
        200
    ));
}
```